# Filter by any text found within div

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, filtering, show-hide

I have been trying to figure out a way to change my current search filter so that any text found within each box's div can be searched, rather than just filtering by each that contains the class 'name'. Does anyone know any simple solutions for adjusting this code so that any additional text can be searched from the same search box? I appreciate any suggestions or ideas.

http://jsfiddle.net/point71echo/mttgj1tt/1/

The JavaScript currently used:

```
document.getElementById("box").oninput=function(){
    for (var i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName("name").length;i++) {
        if (document.getElementsByClassName("name")[i].innerHTML.match(new RegExp(document.getElementById("box").value, "gi"))) {
            document.getElementsByClassName("name")[i].parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.style.display="inline-block";
        } else {       document.getElementsByClassName("name")[i].parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.style.display="none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *I need to...* is not exactly a question.

Comment: @LcSalazar - I apologize if my originally posted question came off as egregiously sloppy or like no effort was expended. As an invaluable resource to my progress in learning programming, I have a great amount of respect for the rules of this website. Thank you for your feedback. I know better for the future.

Comment: That's ok. Always keep in mind that a well formed question will help future users seeking for the same issue, and you may be upvoted for that... Anyway, I hope you manage to find the assistance you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was provided this answer on a separate question posted. It works exactly as I hoped it would.

http://jsfiddle.net/mttgj1tt/3/

```
document.getElementById("box").oninput=function(){

    for (var i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName("connect-cat").length;i++) {
        if (document.getElementsByClassName("name")[i].innerHTML.match(new RegExp(document.getElementById("box").value, "gi")) || document.getElementsByClassName("category")[i].innerHTML.match(new RegExp(document.getElementById("box").value, "gi"))) {
          document.getElementsByClassName("connect-cat")[i].style.display="inline-block";
        } else {
          document.getElementsByClassName("connect-cat")[i].style.display="none";
        }
    }

}
```